# Métodos com vários parâmetros PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário onde irá armazenar os dados da ficha médica do funcionário em uma base de dados. O problema é que esse formulário tem mais de 30 campos. Estou usando POO para cadastrar dessa forma:

```
$metodos->cadastrarFichaMedica($idFuncionario,$tipoSanguineo,$planoSaude,$calendarioVacinal,$nomeContatoI,$telefoneFixoI,$nomeContatoII,$telefoneFixoII,$nomeContatoIII,$telefoneFixoIII,$viveCom,$doencasTeve,$alergias,$qualOutrosAlergia,$atrasoDesenvolvimento,$qualOutrosAtraso,$pcd,$problemasCoracao,$qualProblemaCoracao,$acompanhamentoProblemasCoracao,$qualAcompanhamentoProblemaCoracao,$alergiaMedicamento,$qualAlergiaMedicamento,$intoleranciaGluten,$qualIntoleranciaGluten,$tomaMedicamento,$cirurgia,$ficouInternado,$problemasPeso,$qualTratamentoEspecializado,$qualTratamentoEspecializado,$observacoes);
```

Página da classe:

```
public function cadastrarFichaMedica($idFuncionario,$tipoSanguineo,$planoSaude,$calendarioVacinal,$nomeContatoI,$telefoneFixoI,$nomeContatoII,$telefoneFixoII,$nomeContatoIII,$telefoneFixoIII,$viveCom,$doencasTeve,$alergias,$qualOutrosAlergia,$atrasoDesenvolvimento,$qualOutrosAtraso,$pcd,$problemasCoracao,$qualProblemaCoracao,$acompanhamentoProblemasCoracao,$qualAcompanhamentoProblemaCoracao,$alergiaMedicamento,$qualAlergiaMedicamento,$intoleranciaGluten,$qualIntoleranciaGluten,$tomaMedicamento,$cirurgia,$ficouInternado,$problemasPeso,$qualTratamentoEspecializado,$qualTratamentoEspecializado,$observacoes){
// Faço o cadastro
}
```

O problema é que ficou muito grande e gostaria de saber como posso resolver isso? A minha ideia era dividir em duas ou mais partes, mas como eu poderia fazer dentro dos bons hábitos de programação?

Comment: Quebre em linhas. PHP não precisa ter tudo numa linha só. Bom hábito é saber programar só. O melhor hábito mesmo é não usar POO em PHP, pq é um desperdicio de recursos - pense comigo, os objetos servem mara manter estado, e PHP não mantém. E se é pra usar POO, não adianta por tudo misturado na classe. Isso não é POO, é uma função disfarçada (PHPeiro faz muito isso). Faça tudo bonitinho com funções, que fica melhor. Quando tiver domínio, aí dá pra usar POO (mas quando tiver domínio de verdade, vai ver que é melhor não usar em PHP. Pode ver que só sai porcaria em POO com PHP praticamente)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reduzindo a quantidade de parâmetros

Você pode criar um objeto para agrupar todos esses dados ou então utilizar um array para isso. Cada uma dessas abordagens tem seus prós e contras, mas ambas servem como uma alternativa melhor do que uma quantidade imensa de parâmetros.

Assinatura do método com uso de um array:

```
public function cadastrarFichaMedica(array $dadosCadastro){
 // Implementaçao para fazer o cadastro
}
```

Assinatura do método com um objeto que agrupa os parâmetros:

```
public function cadastrarFichaMedica(Ficha $ficha){
 // Implementação para fazer o cadastro
}
```

No caso do segundo exemplo, o objeto seria uma entidade utilizada para juntar todos os dados e dar um significado mais legível para eles. Isso é benéfico para não ter que alterar a assinatura do método caso um novo valor surja.

Answer (score 2):

Crie uma classe com todas as propriedades

```
class FichaMedica {

public $idFuncionario;
...
```

Eu também recomendaria usar as propriedades por `$classe->propriedade` em vez de criar uma função `setPropriedade` ou usar métodos mágicos para obter por [questão de performance](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625191431/https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php).

E depois altere o método para receber apenas um parâmetro

```
public function cadastrarFichaMedica($fichaMedica){}
```

Dependendo da versão do php, você ainda pode tipar a função assim:

```
public function cadastrarFichaMedica(FichaMedica $fichaMedica){}
```

No geral, se eu vejo que uma função há mais de 4 parâmetros, eu analiso e tento quebrar ela em mais funções ou refatorar a lógica da função para aceitar por exemplo uma classe que segurará os valores.

Comment: Obrigado a todos!